# AZURE Estimate time to upload

Tags: azure

I need get an estimate about how long time the data upload to Azure Backup will take.

Is there some tool to achieve it?

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Lucas Gustavo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas

The best way is to test a sample upload using http://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Upload. It should help you get some estimates.